# Redshift For External Users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds

I have data in S3 and RDS, and use AWS Glue + Athena as a DW currently.

My customers (500+) are:

1. Internal customers: for querying (SQL) data and reporting (hence Athena)
2. External customers: for querying (SQL) their data, hooking up the the data warehouse to a BI product (e.g. Tableau) for reporting

Questions:

1. Is Redshift a better DW (vs Athena/Glue) or RDS?
2. How do I setup the DB so that it is appropriate for external customers to access a limited subset of data of the DW?

What I think:

1. Redshift is better for concurrent SQL queries, scalability, performance etc and is able to integrate with the most common BI resources.
2. Redshift is not good for limiting access / I have not seen a smart way of restricting access at a *table* level. One option is to 'copy' the data into a new schema but this means duplication of data. In RDS (PostgreSQL) you can create a view of the data and expose that to specific clients only. If there is a smart way to tackle this I am curious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon Redshift has the ability to grant and revoke access at the table level.

See:

- [GRANT - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GRANT.html)
- [REVOKE - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_REVOKE.html)

You can also put users in **Groups** and apply the access permissions to the group. Thus, put all external users in the same group.

Comment: Thanks! What was confusing is would I need to set up IAM for external users or simply a username/password/DB host link would be sufficient? I thought they would be blocked somehow as they are external users with no access to the AWS console the Redshift has been built inside. Also, can I have this process automated through a Lambda also given it is a SQL command?

Comment: You can [Use IAM Authentication to Generate Temporary Database User Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/generating-user-credentials.html) and put them into groups, or just generate users within the database and have people login directly. I suspect most people just login directly, but this depends upon your organization's security policies.

Comment: This would mean opening the access of the AWS account to the user though? This is what I was trying to avoid. If you have 500+ customers, and 1 IAM per user, this starts to become difficult.

Comment: You do not need to use IAM. You can create a User within Redshift, put them in Groups and assign permissions to either the User or the Group. No need to use IAM.

Comment: @ohn Rotenstein - for external users I would provide the 'group' username/password and that is sufficient for them to plug into Tableau for example and query the tables?

Comment: No, there is no login for "groups". Instead, you would create a User for them with a username and password, which they would use to login. If every User requires different access permissions, then grant access to each User. However, if all of these types of Users should have the same access, then put all those Users into a Group and then assign permissions to the Group. This is simpler to manage.

Comment: the issue is I have table1 with say, google and apple data. I cannot grant permission on select * from table1 where client = google for example. It seems the only way around this is to adjust the ETL itself and load in client level tables?

Comment: You can use a `CREATE VIEW` with a `WHERE` clause and then grant access to the View. This will limit their access only to desired rows.

Comment: interesting, but this will be 1 table and many views (1 per client) still correct? Does this affect Redshift in any way or the end customer in terms of querying etc?

Comment: The performance impact would be the same as using a `WHERE` statement on a query. If the login username is the same as a value in the table, you could use [CURRENT_USER](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CURRENT_USER.html), therefore requiring only one view that gives a custom result to every user. For example: `CREATE VIEW ... WHERE client = CURRENT_USER`

Comment: There could be multiple customers trying to query the table at the same time though. :)

Comment: It does not matter if multiple customers are using the same View. Please note that it is the Create Statement that would include a reference to the reserved word `CURRENT_USER`, which will automatically substitute the login name of the current user. Thus, the view will automatically show different information to each user, based upon their login name. The view is actually translated into a query on the underlying table (it does not contain any data within the view itself).